# How to remove wrong indentation of linguex examples in footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, linguistics, linguex

Footnotes of the `scrbook` class come with a default indentation. Unfortunately, `linguex` seems to ignore it and falls back on the margins of the main text.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}           
\usepackage{linguex} 
\begin{document}

This is where the footnote attaches.\footnote{Here comes an example sentence within a footnote:

\ex. Here it is.

And now it's over.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any idea how I can tell linguex to behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linguex` redefines the `\footnotetext` which seems to be incompatible to `scrbook`: Try this:

```
\footnote{Here comes an example sentence within a footnote:\\
\parbox{\linewidth}{\ex. Here it is.

}
And now it's over.}
```

One needs to add `\\` before `\parbox` here, in order to avoid the indentation with `\parindent`.

Comment: This solves the immediate problem, thanks! But then you have to take back parindents manually: `\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\ex. Here it is. ` Is there a way to accomplish this automatically?

Comment: sure, but you can test if you are in a footnote and then using a `\parbox` and not outside of a footnote

Comment: yes, but that's not the problem I was referring to. Even if I use `\parbox` only in footnotes, I have to add `\noindent` in certain cases in order to eliminate the `\parindent`.

Comment: Give an example. I cannot see such a case.

Comment: See my addition to your answer.